# Send List values by post method

Tags: android, json, list, arraylist

I have a response from my web service:

```
{
  "UserId": 4,
  "EquipmentId": 1,
  "ScheduleName": "sample string 4",
  "Notes": "sample string 5",
  "StartDate": "2016-04-09",
  "time": [
    {
      "StartTime": "00:00:00",
      "EndTime": "00:30:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

For this I created two classes:

```
public class AddScheduleReqParser {

    @SerializedName(GsonKey.USER_ID)
    public String UserId;

    @SerializedName(GsonKey.EQUIPMENT_ID)
    public String EquipmentId;

    @SerializedName(GsonKey.SCHEDULE_NAME)
    public String ScheduleName;

    @SerializedName(GsonKey.NOTES)
    public String Notes;    

    @SerializedName(GsonKey.START_DATE_STRING)
    public String StartDate;    

    public List<AddScheduleSubReqParser> time;

}
```

and second class:

```
public class AddScheduleSubReqParser {

    @SerializedName(GsonKey.START_TIME)
    public String StartTime;

    @SerializedName(GsonKey.END_TIME)
    public String EndTime;

}
```

I am sending this response by post method

```
mAddScheduleReqParser.UserId = abc;
mAddScheduleReqParser.EquipmentId = "1";
mAddScheduleReqParser.ScheduleName = "Schedule";
mAddScheduleReqParser.Notes = "notes";
mAddScheduleReqParser.StartDate = "2016-04-09";

mAddScheduleSubReqParser.StartTime = "00:30:00";
mAddScheduleSubReqParser.EndTime = "1:00:00"
```

But values are not storing in Start time and time.

How can I send Start time and End Time values?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- make AddScheduleSubReqParser implement Serializable
- Convert the List to byte array
- You can just use the byte array or convert the byte array to string using Base64 in java utility.